# How would I go about fixing unexpected tokens in an embed command/adding in a <user mention> feature?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, command

I'm coding a little bot project, and to challenge myself, I decided to make a new command. The command is supposed to make an embed, and in that embed, [mention both the target user and the person who used the command] , [Embed a short video]

- Code

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "bonk",
    description: "bonks someone",
    category: "funsies",
    command: true,
    execute(message, args, Discord) {
        const bonkEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("#cc4371")
            .setTitle("<@user> BONKED <@target user>")
            .setDescription("[somethin, idfk]")
            .setThumbnail("https://discord.com/channels/774446440252309524/881660577351630849/887115025775476747")
            .addFields({ name: "you got bonked!", value: "https://discord.com/channels/774446440252309524/881660577351630849/887110690719010847" }),
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter('~~lmao~~');


            message.channel.send(bonkEmbed);

        }
    };
```

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'impostor',
    description: 'Calls someone an impostor.',
    category: 'funsies',
    command: true,
    execute(message, args) {
        const user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
        var receiver = "<@!" + user + ">";
        message.channel.send(receiver + " was the impostor", {
            files: ['https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/716942890089316383/755907669453438996/among_us_lmao.png?width=356&height=475']
        });
    },
};
```

I'm using the latter of the two codes as a type of scaffolding for the former, due to my inexperience with javascript. I used an already existing format for the embedding, but that's giving me problems in command prompt. It does not expect certain tokens that are essential for this command to work, and I'ven't a clue how to fix them.

Comment: Maybe considering what you exactly mean by [Embed a short video], as Discord still hasn't implemented the ability to add mp4 files or any thing similar, but you can use gifs/images. The question you're asking is still rather bland, consider reformatting! Thanks

Comment: Also consider adding the errors you are facing so we are able to assist you better

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you **can not** add videos, gifs to embeds. Also, you can't add mentions to embed's **title**. They just do not work so this will not display correctly:

```js
.setTitle("<@user> BONKED <@target user>")
```

You have I'm guessing "placeholder" for the `.setDescription()` part, which I would highly suggest you use as "the title"

```js
.setDescription("<@user> BONKED <@target user>")
```

Of course the `<@user>` and `<@target user>` will not display anything mentionable, but I guess again this is just a placeholder for you.

Answer (score 0):

You Cant Add Mentions To Embed Title, Try To Use The Mentions In Description

Btw It wont mention the users, its like a text...

Also You Are Setting A Message Link As Your Thumbnail And Field!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).